# WordPress shortcode only accepts default attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, attributes, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

Im currently trying to code my own shortcode to use the YouTube API on my WordPress website. My Code works also but only with the default attributes of the shortcode. The appended attributes via shortcode self are ignored by my code.

Can anyone help me? I googled a lot but I didnt found anything like this. I think I made everything like the codex way but maybe you know more.
Here is my code:

```
function api_youtube_integration($atts, $content = null) {
    $a = shortcode_atts(array(
        'class'         => '',
        'videoCount'    => 5,
        'bottomBar'     => true
    ), $atts);
ob_start();
    ?>

    <div data-video="<?php echo esc_html($a['videoCount']); ?>">Test</div>
<?php 
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('youtubeAPI', 'api_youtube_integration');
```

My shortcode: [youtubeAPI videoCount=12]
The code only returns 5 as videCount but not the 12...

Best Regards Lukas

Comment: I can't see anything wrong here. May add a `var_dump($atts);` at the very top of the function and make sure you are importing the attributes like you expect?

Comment: I fixed it!
I dont know why but wordpress doesnt like array names with uppercase words like "videoCount". I changed all attributes to lowercase and it works fine. But shouldnt it work alsolike my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently attributes passed to `shortcode_atts()` are always converted to lowercase. [Official docs:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Handling_Attributes)

> Attribute names are always converted to lowercase before they are passed into the handler function. Values are untouched. [myshortcode FOO="BAR"] produces $atts = array( 'foo' => 'BAR' ).

So you'll either need to make sure all options are lowercase, or use underscores to separate words.